# Использование String как название массива

Tags: java, массивы, строки

Нужно создавать массивы ArrayList с названием, как ник игрока. Вот я получил ник в String.
`String plname = p.getName();`
Вот я попытался использовать его в качестве названия массива.

```
ArrayList<Player> plname = new ArrayList<Player>();
```

Но вот проблема: он жалуется, чтобы я переименовал "plname". Как использовать 
String plname в качестве названия массива?

Answer (score 3):

Никак, в Java переменные не объявляются динамически. Используйте [HashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html):

```
Map<String, List<Player>> players = new HashMap<>();
players.put(plname, new ArrayList<>());
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Полезная информация на будущее (наверное), но я нашёл решение своей задачи (которая не в теме), не трогая имя игрока. Я просто создал массив с массивами, а кол-во массивов в этом массиве равно другим массивам... В общем, не буду вас путать, тема потеряла актуальность за столь короткий срок, но спасибо за ответ.